# Is it possible to retrieve the CPU that created a WDFREQUEST?

Tags: c, windows, device-driver, wdk, wdf

I am trying to affinitise the completion of CompleteRequest to the CPU that originally issued the request. Is there a way to retrieve the CPU that issued the request during FdoDeviceControl or any onother way to see where the request came from before it entered the dispatch queue?

Comment: Retrieving the CPU after that dispatch has happened is of course simple enough. But am I guaranteed that the callback function runs on the same core as the issues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you are in a DPC routine it's too late to tell where the request originated.  You need to call KeGetCurrentProcessorNumberEx() before you queue the request to a DPC queue.  I assume the request is an IRP...?

Comment: David, I am using KMDF to handle request so the IRP is wrapped in a WDFREQUEST struct. At the point I see the request, it ha already passed through an I/O queue

Comment: If you are using KMDF then you need to call WdfDeviceInitSetIoInCallerContextCallback().  This will allow you to peek at the I/O request before it gets place onto the kmdf I/O queue, you will be running in the process context of the I/O initiator and you will be on the core that initiated the I/O.  From there you can call KeGetCurrentProcessorNumberEx() and save the result.

Comment: Listed as an answer David, thanks. On a related note, am I guarateed that EvtDeviceWdmIrpPreprocess is also called in the context of the client (I am using guaranteed forward progress queues, so I need to make sure I ALWAYS get the call, which it looks like SetIoInCallerContextCallback doesnt do)

Comment: That's unusual, I think you should always get the callback using WdfDeviceInitSetIoInCallerContextCallback(). Make sure you call it before calling WdfDeviceCreate().  In any case if there is a filter driver above you then, the original context may be lost.